# UDP Python - data only sent once despite recalling function

Tags: python, udp, osc

I've successfully created/adapted a working OSC python script which can accept and print OSC data from external hardware to my computer.

I'm currently trying to send this data into another program. The script is working except it will only send out the first UDP message. In the console i can see the script is working as it prints out various aspects of the code when osc data is received.

The UDP receiver is working on the other side as im sending other messages into the external program.

Included are parts of the code which may help identify the problem. Any help is appreciated, strange the rest of the function is called again and working, just not the last line of sending the data...

I did try a separate function and calling that function at end of osc handler function, but the same issue of only sending the first UDP message remains.

Thanks in advance!

```html
ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) #Gets IP of MacBook Pro

receive_address = ip, 4567 # MacBook Pro Adress, Outgoing Port
send_address = '192.168.#.##', 9112 # iPhone Adress, Incoming Port
 
# ------------------ UDP to send  IP/ Port Settings ----------------- #


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1" # Local machine to send data internally
UDP_PORT = 1234 # Local UDP Port

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))


# --------------------- OSC Server and client start -------------------------------- #
 
# Initialize the OSC server and the client.
s = OSC.OSCServer(receive_address)
c = OSC.OSCClient()
c.connect(send_address)
 
s.addDefaultHandlers()

def multixy1(add, tags, stuff, source): #osc handler
 
 print "Message received:"
 msg = OSC.OSCMessage()
 print msg
 msg.setAddress(addr)
 msg.append(stuff)
 c.send(msg)
 
        # Testing osc is working/updating with each message input #
        print "Raw OSC Mesagge = ", msg
 print "X Value: ", stuff[0]

 UDP_to_Send = str(msg)
 
        print "UDP Send message = ", UDP_Send
 print sock
 print datetime.now()
 
        tm = str(datetime.now())
 print "size = ", sys.getsizeof(tm), "bytes"
 
        sock.send(tm) # this line does not appear to be called again despite the rest of the function being called

s.addMsgHandler("/1/fader1",  multixy1)

# ----------- Starting OSC server ----------- #

print "\nStarting OSCServer."

st = threading.Thread( target = s.serve_forever )
st.start()

# Loop while threads are running.
try :
    while 1 :
 time.sleep(0.1)
 
except KeyboardInterrupt :
    print "\nClosing OSCServer."
    s.close()
    print "Waiting for Server-thread to finish"
    st.join()
    print "Done"
```

Comment: whitespace(indention) is extremely important ... is that line supposed to be less indented?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, apologies, I copied that line into the snippet wrong, I can confirm all the whitespace and formatting is correct! I'll amend the code above, appreciate your help!

Comment: As a side note, `sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` creates a TCP socket not UDP.

Comment: Well spotted, thank you! I believe TCP would be more suited for this than UDP, but perhaps I am wrong. I appreciate your help!